# Wordpress-Woocommerce: Product Variations "Select All" and "Select None" buttons not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was hoping someone could help me find out why in my installation of Woocommerce the "select all", "select none" and also "add new" buttons do not show up, nor there any autocomplete (I read somewhere it should be there).

The attributes are set because if I type in manually some values that are defined in the attributes and save the product, it will appear on the frontpage's variation selectior. But even if it recognized, that value I enter manually doesn't appear stylized like in the image below, only in plain text .

[Reference](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/) image where you can see the buttons I'm writing about:

[image]

Screenshot of my current situation:
[image]

Screenshot of current attributes:
[image]

This is a clean installation of Wordpress, in European Portuguese. I've tried disabling themes and plugins but it didn't make any difference.

I was hoping to find some help in solving or debugging this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your attributes page from the dashboard?

Comment: @MichaelT Hi, I've added a screenshot as requested. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Products → Attributes and edit your global attributes. Specifically, change the type from textfield to selectfield.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the attributes to the Products-> attributes section, Once you add the attributes it will shows automatically in the single product page. and you can select the attributes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. That's exactly the issue, it doesn't do that. Here's a screenshot where you can see it doesn't recognize the attibutes (the one written in blongs to attibutes already in the database - if I save it keeps it and it will work on the frontend - only no auto-fill or select all). Image here:  http://i.imgur.com/z7cXWHO.png (it's in Portuguese but I think is readable)